# Angular Material: "export 'MaterialComponents' was not found in './material/material.module'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm new on Angular and I have some problems to export a material module. This is the error:

> (Failed to compile.) ./src/app/app.module.ts 17:12-30 "export
>   'MaterialComponents' was not found in './material/material.module'

This is the Material Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

const MaterialComponents = [
  MatButtonModule
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [MaterialComponents],
  imports: [MaterialComponents],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

App Module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialComponents } from './material/material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialComponents
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Which Angular version are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct it to `MaterialModule`

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule //< -- HERE
  ],
```

Also, note that you dont  need to `import` and `export` same thing if you want to create a common shared module which will consolidate all other `modules` just do:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [MatButtonModule, OtherMatModules...],
  imports: [],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

**Although**, the error is coming because you have not put `export` keyword in front of

```
export const MaterialComponents = [
  MatButtonModule
];
```

---

Even if you put export, you'll end up getting error so simply use what I suggested above. with your values you are passing as `array` in `array`

In your case, Below

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [MaterialComponents],
  imports: [MaterialComponents],
})
```

is equivalent to:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [[MatButtonModule]],
  imports: [[MatButtonModule]],
})
```

which is nested array, and a wrong syntax for angular

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

const MaterialComponents = [
  MatButtonModule
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [MaterialComponents],
  imports: [MaterialComponents],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

This equates to an array of arrays:

```js
@NgModule({
  exports: [[MatButtonModule ]],
  imports: [[MatButtonModule ]],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```js
@NgModule({
  exports: MaterialComponents,
  imports: MaterialComponents,
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Hi! I try this way, but in my app.modules.ts, the error continuous: declares 'MaterialComponents' locally, but it is not exported

Comment: @GabrielJúniordeSouza : Just add `export` as suggested in my answer